# Disadvantages of unencrypted traffic between CloudFront and other AWS services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

I am running an app on Elastic Beanstalk and it communicates over HTTP between CloudFront. So client to CF is via HTTPS, but from CF to EB and back is unencrypted. What are the practical disadvantages of this? I do realise this is a security risk, but what exactly does that mean? Surely this is not end to end encrypted, but from a security perspective, what exactly is the risk? If an ISP is hacked, then data is leaked?

Comment: Since, EB is exposed with http, someone can directly hit it and use it without CF.

Comment: wasnt the question